# How to update a multi-select and have it actually show the new options in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, multi-select

I can't believe it but I found some JS code that works perfectly in IE 11 but does not work in Chrome (version 81).

I am updating one multi select from another, keeping the options sorted. So I have a function for it:

```js
    /**
     * Move the options defined by <sel> from select tag <from> to select tag <to>
     * @param from   The source SELECT tag jQuery object
     * @param to     The destination SELECT tag jQuery object
     * @param sel    Either: "option" for all, or "option:selected"
     */
    function moveOpt(from, to, sel) {
        var opts = from.children(sel).removeAttr('selected').remove().get();
        opts = opts.concat(to.children('option').remove().get());
        opts.sort(function (a, b) {
            return a.value.localeCompare(b.value);
        });
        to.append(opts);
        /*
        // Chrome doesn't re-render the opts until they are selected and then focus is lost ???
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            to.children('option').attr('selected', 'selected').trigger('click');
            from.trigger('focus');
            to.children('option').removeAttr('selected');
        }, 1);
         */
    }
```

This works perfectly in IE 11, but in chrome, the options get moved, but you can't see them in the browser.  They are there because if you "inspect" the SELECT element, all the OPTION tags are there, and also doing `$(to).children().length` shows the correct number.

If I uncomment the ugly HACK (the `window.setTimeout()` call) then Chrome finally will show the options correctly. But it is NUTS to have to do this.  I must be doing something wrong. Anyone know what that something is?

[Here is a JS fiddle showing the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/user96451384/bkaLq0td/3/) - Running it in IE (read-only mode) shows it working, Chrome does not.

#### UPDATE

I tried upgrading jQuery from 1.10.2 to 3.5.0 and still did not work.

Also as @ZacharyYaro points out it works in Chrome 80 but not 81.

Changing this:

```
to.append(opts);
```

To this:

```
var toElm = to.get()[0];
$.each(opts, function(i,v) { toElm.appendChild(v); });
```

Fixes the problem.

Comment: Interestingly, it appears your Fiddle also works in Chrome 80, and then breaks in Chrome 81.  It appears [using the built-in `selectElement.add` function instead of jQuery (JSFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/ZMYaro/qpu5b6h9) works in Chrome 81 (as does `selectElement.appendChild`), which makes me wonder whether Chrome 81 broke something used by jQuery's `$element.append(array)` function.

Comment: Thanks @ZacharyYaro -  I was able to work around the issue by using `.appendChild()` instead of jQuery's `.append()`.  I wonder if a newer version of jQuery would also fix it? I note I am using jQuery 1.10.2, and I can supposedly go up to 2.2.4 and still be compatible with bootstrap 3. I will try that also.  I think you can submit an answer if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Resubmitting my comment as an answer since it worked for you)
It appears your Fiddle also works in Chrome 80, and then breaks in Chrome 81. It appears [using the built-in `selectElement.add` function instead of jQuery (JSFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/ZMYaro/qpu5b6h9) works in Chrome 81, so it seems Chrome 81 just broke something used by jQuery's `$element.append(arrayOfElements)` function.